# Does SAGA in QGIS processing can support no ascii name?

Tags: qgis-plugins, saga, qgis-processing

From Qgis, I am calling through Processing the Saga algs "clipgridwithpolygon"

raster_inside_poly = processing.runalg("saga:clipgridwithpolygon",
                my_raster_temp,
                my_edges,
                **my_new_raster**)

Since **my_new_raster** name is all ascii. It's fine.
When no ascii is presented to Processing and SAGA crash with "Encode exception"

My Question : 
is this a limitation on the SAGA side or on Processing ?
Someone can propose a solution ?

*Problem experienced on Win8 Qgis 2.12.2 Processing 2.12.2 Saga 2.1.2*

Comment: Analysing the stack error, Processing tracks "ascii name" when calling Saga alg "Contour lines from grid"

`iso_in_layer = processing.runalg("saga:contourlinesfromgrid",
                    my_new_raster,
                    isoMin, isoMax, isoInterlignes,
                    None)`

The grid my_new_raster has an unicode name created by saga:clipgridwithpolygon
Processing trace :
`print 'Unable to execute algorithm\n' + msg
UnicodeEncodeError "ascii" ....`

Pushing the question to Qgis.